# gcc floating point behaviour changes

Tags: gcc, floating-point

We are looking at porting a set of applications written in C++ from gcc 4.3.2 to gcc 4.8.x, essentially as part of moving from CentOS 5 to CentOS 7. I remember doing something similar when upgrading a different application from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012, and finding that the floating point handling had been changed between versions of the compiler, causing the application output to change. In that case, setting a compiler flag reverted to the original behaviour.

Given that a requirement for this is that the application should produce exactly the same output, I was wondering if anyone was aware whether the floating point options/behaviour had changed between the 2 versions of gcc above, and, if so, whether there would be compiler options to allow one to revert to the gcc 4.3.2 behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What flags are you currently passing?

Comment: Looking at the make file, the only flags are "-g -O0 -m32"

Comment: With x87, the exact results are kind of random. Does `-fexcess-precision=standard` help? (related options: `-std=c99`, `-mfpmath=sse`)

Comment: I don't know if anything changed between those two versions but things change at 4.9: http://www.exploringbinary.com/real-c-rounding-is-perfect-gcc-now-converts-correctly/

Comment: @MarcGlisse Couldn't find the '-fexcess-precision' option in the man pages for gcc 4.3. sse was the cause of my problems between VS 2008 and 2012, so that might help. Ultimately, as long as I can get the newer compiler to behave the same as the older compiler, I'm not worried about the exact results - just needs to be consistent between the 2 so that I can show that no mistakes have been made in porting the code itself. Would using '-ffloat-store' and explicitly enabling sse in both compilers cause the 2 compilers to behave the same, or do I need to delve through the plethora of other options?

Comment: @RickRegan That is useful to know - I will make a note, as at some point, there will be a need to go to the latest gcc compiler.

Comment: float-store and fpmath=see should be redundant, one or the other is likely sufficient.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Great thanks. I will try out when I have the new compiler installed.